# Brew completion doesn't work when it is aliased

Tags: homebrew, zsh, tab-completion

I have alias:`alias br="env PATH=${PATH/\/Users\/${USER}\/\.pyenv\/shims:?/} brew"`
and also `compdef _brew br`

But it only suggests the files and directories.
How can I get the brew options completion?

I tried `compdef br=brew` and `compdef _brew br=brew` but it doesn't work.

I'm using zsh without oh-my-zsh in mac.

Comment: What's the point of `env`? You can totally remove it and achieve what you want. The reason your `compdef` doesn't work is because alias is expanded before completion. Therefore, if you remove the `env`, you don't even need the `compdef`.

Comment: When I do ```brew doctor``` I get some warning and to remove it I had to alias this I think. Completion work in other alias so I want to know way it doesn't work only in brew.

Comment: I think ```env``` is the problem. If I remove it and test other alias such as ```br=brew``` completion works.

Comment: If you have resolved the problem, you can post an answer to this yourself and then mark it accepted, to help future searchers with the same sort of question.

Comment: I meant remove env and keep the `PATH=` part.